# encountering poi exceptions while running my Java code

Tags: java, apache

The exceptions are :

```
         Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should contain a content type part [M1.13]
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:41)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:218)
at defg.jButton4ActionPerformed(defg.java:984)
at defg.access$900(defg.java:86)
at defg$9.actionPerformed(defg.java:547)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)

... a lot more [edited for brevity]
```

Code snipplet [copied from comment]:

```
try { 
  Thread.sleep(1000); 
}
catch (InterruptedException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(def.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
}

try {
  System.out.println("njfklasndjklasdnl");
  File inputFile = new File(str1);
  File inputFile1 = new File (str2);
  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
  XSSFWorkbook wb1 =new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile1));
  System.out.println(wb1.getNumberOfSheets());
  XSSFSheet sheettemp=wb1.createSheet("temp");
  XSSFSheet sheeta= wb1.createSheet("Repeatitions");
```

Comment: Are we supposed to magically understand how your code looks like ?

Comment: Please, leave out the majority of the call stack and post the code of defg.jButton4ActionPerformed(defg.java:984) instead.

Comment: XSSFWorkbook wb1 =new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile1));

Comment: the code is too long cant fit it here

Comment: @ammoQ 
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(def.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
try {System.out.println("njfklasndjklasdnl");
File inputFile = new File(str1);
File inputFile1 = new File (str2);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
XSSFWorkbook wb1 =new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile1));
System.out.println(wb1.getNumberOfSheets());
XSSFSheet sheettemp=wb1.createSheet("temp");
XSSFSheet sheeta= wb1.createSheet("Repeatitions");

Comment: My best guess is that those files are not valid .xlsx files... do other programs like Excel and LibreOffice Calc open them correctly?

Comment: @ammoQ Thanks man it worked now dr is some exception like Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a new project, adding only the necessary jars (P